# Doctrine2 __constructor not called when using $em->find(); ? How to load entity properly?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm learning doctrine2, and having a problem how to call constructor automatically.
For example, in my entity I have

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class User{
   ....
   public function __construct() {
       exit('in');
   }
}
```

and when I get the object this way:

```
$userObj = $em->find('User', 1);
```

I do get that object from database, but constructor is never called. 
I want to put some common things in constructor, like validation rules, or even to put sample code from the doctrine documentation like

```
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
```

This ofcourse works when I create new object in code for creating a user like

```
$user = new User(); //now constructor works just fine
```

Now, what is the "proper" way of getting the entity? I doubt I have to call constructor manually each time I user $em->find() with $user0bj->__construct(); ? This would kinda sucks then... Or I should use something other then ->find() to get single entity properly?
I know I can user @PrePersist, and I am using it to actually do validation checks etc. 
I guess that I'm probably missing something here, or I'm trying to use constructor in a poor way. Thanks for any explanations and guides!

Comment: So far I'm using separate setUp() method that is called in both constructor and also with @PostLoad event, it sets what I need to be set in object both when object is created with new Obj(); and it is called when obj is fetched from database. It might help someone with similar dilemma.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that `find` or similar isn't expected to call the constructor...

You need to hook into the [@PostLoad](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#postload) event.

Comment: So this is where I will put my code I want to be in a constructor? I can see there is a line that says " if ($this->id) {", will this line be called when I create a new object like "$obj = new Obj" ? Or I should put this in wakeup: $this->__constructor ?

Comment: Yea, it's better if you call the constructor from your __wakeup method, saves duplicating code.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will try this method and hopefully it will fit in my general plan of work.

Comment: This is very bad style, you will get unexpected behavior with this. You dont need to set the Arraycollection again, when $em->find() is called, Doctrine will do that for you. If you need to execute initialization logic on your entity you should use the @PostLoad event.

Comment: So you are suggesting to put $this->__construct() in some method that is @PostLoad event, right?
I would like to set bunch of other things as I want to inherit main object and have some settings in constructor, but editing the object messes with my plans as __construct is not called when using $em->find();

Comment: I've added @PostLoad to actual constructor and it works as I expect it to work (so far). Will this mess some things up?

Comment: Oh @PostLoad... total forgot :|
Thanks, Berbelei.

Answer (score 3):

doctrine uses reflection to instantiate your object without invoking your constructor.

> Since PHP 5.4 , you can use reflection to instanciate a class without
>   calling the constructor using
>   **ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor**

the instantiator of doctrine use it like :

```
private function buildFactory(string $className) : callable
{
    $reflectionClass = $this->getReflectionClass($className);

    if ($this->isInstantiableViaReflection($reflectionClass)) {
        return [$reflectionClass, 'newInstanceWithoutConstructor'];
    }

    $serializedString = sprintf(
        '%s:%d:"%s":0:{}',
        is_subclass_of($className, Serializable::class) ? self::SERIALIZATION_FORMAT_USE_UNSERIALIZER : self::SERIALIZATION_FORMAT_AVOID_UNSERIALIZER,
        strlen($className),
        $className
    );

    $this->checkIfUnSerializationIsSupported($reflectionClass, $serializedString);

    return static function () use ($serializedString) {
        return unserialize($serializedString);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to call the constuctor of already persisted entity? When you need to validate it you should have done the validation or initializations before you have persisted it. So When you call a already persisted entity there is no point to validate it.
The right place to put validation and other initializations is the constructor method of entity.
Eg.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class User{
   protected $name;
   public function __construct($name) {
       if (isset($name)) {
           //** validate the name here */
           $this->name=$name;
       } else {
           throw new Exception("no user name set!");
       }
   }
}
```

According to the doctrine2 documentation Doctrine2 never calls __construct() method of entities. 
http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/architecture.html?highlight=construct

Comment: Yes, I understand that it never calls __constructor() and that is fine. Now, problem is the editing of entities, for example users. 
There is a form with existing data filled in, and I want to 
$userObj = $em->find('user', $id);
then to update email field
$userObj->setEmail($newEmail);
Now problem is, that my plan was to set validation rules in constructor, for example
function __constructor(){
$fields = array('email', 'required|email|max50');
}

Perhaps I should set these rules manually? There might be need for other things I would like to set or configure or handle each time object is used.

Comment: In your case ,I think you should set the validation in the setEmail($email) method. Eg.
public function setEmail($email){
    //** check here if the email address is valid */
    /** if it's a valid email then set */
    $this->email=$email;
}

Comment: Yeah, I think I will go with this approach. I kinda wanted to make magic setter and getter, I know it is "wrong" but it just works much faster for me to have one setProperties($_POST) then to write each of them. I guess I will get back to the drawing board... Thanks

Comment: Okay, so if the question is raised "why would you call the constructor of already persisted entity", then what is the point of this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#initializing-collections

Without the constructor running, wouldn't that collection always just be null? It certainly doesn't seem like "find" (or any other method like it) creates an instance of ArrayCollection.

Comment: Maybe a dev would expect the constructor of a class to be called when instantiating an object from it...as PHPs `ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor` is not something that you find in a lot of other languages i think. So total legit question in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine ORM will "rewrite" your class, it generate a new class that implement `\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy`

And it rewrite the `construct` method:

```
/**
     * @param \Closure $initializer
     * @param \Closure $cloner
     */
    public function __construct($initializer = null, $cloner = null)
    {

        $this->__initializer__ = $initializer;
        $this->__cloner__      = $cloner;
    }
```

You can see it inside the `cache` folder `${CACHE}/doctrine/orm/Proxies`.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. Since the question was asked in 2011, I am pretty sure a lot has changed since :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need both @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks on the class + @ORM\PostLoad on a specific function of your choice.

Beware! If you put it on the constructor **it will override loaded database data**!

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="dossier")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Dossier
{
    // ...

    /**
     * The normal constructor stays as usual
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->takenActions = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->classifications = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->dossierProblems = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->internalNotes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Triggers after the entity has been loaded in the EntityManager (e.g. Doctrine's ->find() etc...)
     * The constructor does not get called. Some variables still need a default value
     * Must be in combination with "ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks" on the class
     * 
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     */
    public function postLoadCallback(): void
    {
        // Only put a default value when it has none yet
        if (!$this->dossierProblems)
            $this->dossierProblems = new ArrayCollection();
        if (!$this->internalNotes)
            $this->internalNotes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```