# Symfony2: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony, toarray

Hy,

I've a short question about a weird error message I get on my *Symfony 2* project.

I've an entity class `User` which retrieves its roles via *Doctrine*. This works perfectly! But...

I want let the `User implement EquatableInterface`, so I've added the `User::isEqualTo` method. This is where my error occurs. [This line](https://github.com/andi1984/calendar-app/blob/develop/src/Andi1984/CalendarBundle/Entity/User.php#L187), especially `$this->getRoles()`is causing the error:

> Symfony2: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object

But the same `toArray` function usage inside `User::getRoles()` works great on the rest of the project. So I don't get what's wrong here.

Can somebody help me with it? Any help appreciated!

**Update 1**

Looking into the logs and using your current help, here are some insights:

- `$this`in [`getRoles`](https://github.com/andi1984/calendar-app/blob/develop/src/Andi1984/CalendarBundle/Entity/User.php#L139) *always* returns the entity user class, so nothing special there, but
- After each `isEqualTo`call, `$this->roles`returns `null`, after that it doesn't.

**Update 2**

Here are my further insights:

- I've added [Konstantin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376972/konstantin-pereyaslov)'s `is_null`check, but it doesn't solve the actual problem.
- As I could see in the logs during logging in, `refreshUser` is called and everything is perfect. Roles are found. After refreshUser `isEqualTo`is fired and suddenly `$this->roles`becomes null and `get_class($this->roles)`returns user entity class (?!?!?) in comparison to `Doctrine\\ORM\\PersistentCollection`.

When I add the roles to the user's (un)serialize methods everything seems to be fine inside this `isEqualTo` method. He finally is grabbing the roles and I can add my logic to it. Fine! But afterwards Symfony is throwing erros like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892930/unexpected-behaviour-following-changing-entity-relationships) or [that](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3691). In my pov it has something to do with the serialization.

After some readings I've added serialization to the role entity because this seems the standard way to go. Serializing the user and the roles on their own, not (un)serializing the roles inside the user class. But as soon as I'm removing the roles from the user's serializing methods the old problem occurs again and again concerning `$this->roles` is always `null` when isEqualTo is fired. Everytime before and after everything's great, except this method call.

I haven't any clue what's exactly going wrong here.

**Any idea?**

Comment: What is result of `get_class($this)` on [here](https://github.com/andi1984/calendar-app/blob/develop/src/Andi1984/CalendarBundle/Entity/User.php#L139).

Comment: It is always an instance of the user entity class, so nothing special. But always when isEqualTo is called the following $this->roles is null. After that at other getRoles() calls it isn't...

Comment: [It](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773976/doctrine2-constructor-not-called-when-using-em-find-how-to-load-entity) this helpful to you?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is caused by `$this->roles` being not populated at the moment of getRoles() call. It's hard to say what exactly is causing it without going through your other code. An easy solution would be to add a check to your `getRoles()` method at line 138:

```
if ($this->roles === null) {
     return null;
}
```

But I'm not sure that's what you want to do, you probably want to figure out why roles are actually empty at that moment.

Comment: I've added this null check but it doesn't fix the problem (see my second update above).